# Rspec before block and order of processing

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a describe block in rspec and it looks something like this:

```
describe 'Trying to get this to work' do
  object = Class.new('Old Value')

  it "object.value should return #{object.value}" do
    expect(object.value).to eq 'Old Value'
  end

  describe 'Try a before hook' do
    before {
      object.update_value 'New Value'
    }

    it "object.value should return #{object.value}" do
      expect(object.value).to eq 'New Value'
    end
  end
end
```

I am expecting to see this output:

```
Trying to get this to work
object.value should return Old Value
Try a before hook
  object.value should return New Value
```

But this is what I am actually seeing:

```
Trying to get this to work
object.value should return Old Value
Try a before hook
  object.value should return Old Value
```

But the tests pass so I know that in my second example object.value == 'New Value'.

How does Rspec process these blocks and why am I not seeing the updated object value in the description of my second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `let`

```
describe 'Trying to get this to work' do
  let(:object){ Class.new('Old Value') }

  it "object.value should return #{object.value}" do
    expect(object.value).to eq 'Old Value'
  end

  describe 'Try a before hook' do
    let(:object){ Class.new('New Value') }

    it "object.value should return #{object.value}" do
      expect(object.value).to eq 'New Value'
    end
  end
end
```

Also I don't think that you should rely on something external in your descriptions. You should declare `it` more explicitly:

```
it "object.value should return new value"
```

Much simpler!